# Do I need ConcurrentQueue in this case of using Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm reading from 4 XML files asynchronously and want to combine the results into one results file. I'm using ConcurrentQueue but I'm not sure if I need to.

Is the fact that I'm adding to a single collection within a `Task.WhenAll` might cause a concurrency problem? Is the ConcurrentQueue the only way to solve this problem?

Data File Sample (1 of 4)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<states>
  <state id="11" Name="Georgia" Abbrev="GA" Capital="Atlanta" region="" />
  <state id="12" Name="Alabama" Abbrev="AL" Capital="Montgomery" region="" />
  <state id="13" Name="Mississippi" Abbrev="MS" Capital="Jackson" region="" />
  <state id="14" Name="Arkansas" Abbrev="AK" Capital="Little Rock" region="" />
  <state id="15" Name="South Carolina" Abbrev="SC" Capital="Columbia" region="" />
</states>
```

Code

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] _regions = new[] { "ResourceMidwest.xml", "ResourceRockyMountains.xml", "ResourceSoutheast.xml", "ResourceSouthwest.xml" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = GetLocations().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task<statesState[]> GetLocations()
        {
            ConcurrentQueue<statesState> toReturn = new ConcurrentQueue<statesState>();

            var w = await Task.WhenAll(_regions.Select(async region =>
            {
                var r = await GetLocationServices(region);
                var r2 = DeserializeResponse<states>(r);

                foreach (var item in r2.state)
                {
                    toReturn.Enqueue(item);
                }
                return toReturn;
            }));

            return toReturn.ToArray();
        }

        static async Task<string> GetLocationServices(string filename)
        {
            var results = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filename);

            return results;
        }

        static T DeserializeResponse<T>(string r)
        {
            try
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(r))
                {
                    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I'm using ConcurrentQueue but I'm not sure if I need to"_ -- I don't understand your question. Why would you _not_ need `ConcurrentQueue`? The default synchronization context for a console program means that the continuation where elements are added can happen in any thread pool thread, so of course you have the potential for concurrent access. You don't literally need `ConcurrentQueue`, but you need _something_. It's not clear at all from your post what kind of help you actually need. Please explain the question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a to mutate shared state in the concurrent tasks at all.  Instead just return the data and aggregate it in the main thread after all the tasks have run.  eg

```
var states = await Task.WhenAll(_regions.Select(async region =>
{
    var r = await GetLocationServices(region);
    var state = DeserializeResponse<State>(r);
    return state;
}));

foreach (var s in states) ...
```

Comment: What if say, the data file didn't have a region attribute assigned? Could I in the deserialization process (and within the Task.WhenAll) loop through the states and assign the region safely without collisions. Maybe deriving the region from the filename somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  But the basic pattern is that the async code only writes to local objects, and returns them to be collected by `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: After the deserialize statement and before the return state, could I put a loop in there and update all rows assigning the region attribute in the resulting array (variable is called state) safely? Kinda of like I have in the OP where I'm doing the Enqueue. Instead of that I would just update the region attribute.

Comment: Sure.  So long as you're modifying an object that you created in the local scope, it's safe.

Comment: Would that ConcurrentQueue have worked correctly though? Or am I still asking the wrong question there?

Comment: @Rod yes, the `ConcurrentQueue` would have worked correctly. But the technique suggested by David Browne is superior. The less shared state you have, the better.